# How to limit http calls per day in Angular 4 or 5?

Tags: angular, http, angular5

I am making an http call on Submit button but I want to limit that calls (say 10 successful calls) per day.
Can you Please tell me , how can we implement that in Angular 4/5?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Angular` are front-end frameworks. You need a back-end application for this implementation.

- Use `Redis` or other cache solutions.
- Use client IP or other as a unique identification key.
- Check if the key exists, if not, create one.
- If request succeed, increase the value of the key by `INCR` command.
- Check if the value reached 10 of limitation before proceed the request.
- You can set `EXPIRE` time to reset a limitation as well.

`Redis` are not traditional DBs, which means you don't need to waste extra DB queries to do this implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need a backend with a DB counting the number of requests you made that day, and before sending a new request check that DB if the quota hasn't been passed.

saving data across all clients on the front end is not something you can do.